# Get WooCommerce products using REST api without any middleware in Android App

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is it possible to retrieve all WooCommerce product data to android app using REST api with HTTP method.

I've website where I've enabled REST api and I want to retrieve that data into mobile app. Is it possible without any middleware ?

If not, which PHP framework will be easier for this ?

Comment: https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction this may be useful for you..

Comment: They suggest to use middleware, doesn't they ?

Comment: What's wrong in using middleware... why so concerned???

Comment: You just need to call some `REST API URLs` for fetching/uploading your store data... that's it...!!!

Comment: @user3288891 are able to fetch the data from WooCommerce from android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You don't need to use any PHP Framework for this!

What you just need to do is written at this [link](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/). 
And you can find how to call woocommerce rest apis [here](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/new-rest-api-based-on-the-wp-rest-api-in-2-6/)

Then you just need to call the API directly from your android code. You may be using something like [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html#request-json) for doing your network communication in android.

Comment: I,m having the same problem to get the data from woo commerce. Can we do like string request with url please give any way to get the woo-commerce data.